# Changing the href of a link tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the href of a link tag so that when a button is pressed a new style sheet is loaded.

function addcss()
{
var findlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
findlink.href = "stylesheetxhtml.css";
}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't set the `href` directly like that, because `document.getElementsByTagName` returns all the `<link>` tags (as a `NodeList`). If you're positive you only have one, use this:

```
var findlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
findlink[0].href = "stylesheetxhtml.css";
```

If you have multiple `<link>` elements and want to target a specific one, give it an id and use `document.getElementById`:

```
var findlink = document.getElementsById("myLinkId");
findlink.href = "stylesheetxhtml.css";
```

Finally, if you want to create a new `<link>` element, use `document.createElement`:

```
var newLink = document.createElement('link');
newLink.href = "stylesheetxhtml.css";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newlink);
```

Comment: Ah Thank you, just that little bit off lol. so if i had more than one link tag I would have to look for the link with the href I wanted to change. Or would I add change the number 0?  sorry quite new to javascript. Don't worry if your busy. Thanks for your help

Comment: It's easier to just give it an id, instead of looping through all link elements and checking the hrefs.

Comment: Awesome thanks, one more question if you don't mind. How would I get it to go back up to the top of the page once the button was pressed. I tried the function "window.location.reload()" but that obviously
 just reloaded the page without the link change

Answer (score 0):

Man, the most simple way is:
Just type this:
document.querySelector(".search").setAttribute("href","https://www.google.com/");

Now
Make your button do this on click!