# Dynamically changing CSS style files with onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently able to dynamically change style rules directly via JS, but I find this rther limiting and I'd rather be able to to hot-swap entire CSS stylesheet files. Any suggestions?

**My code:**

```
<label>Themes :</label>
<select name="background" id="bg" onchange="changeBg(this)">
    <option value="white">Default</option>
    <option value="#444">Dark</option>
    <option value="teal">Teal</option>
</select>

// Changing Themes
function changeBg(x){
    var body = document.getElementById('body');
    body.style.backgroundColor = x.value;
}
```

**And perhaps I'd have multiple stylesheet definitions, like so:**

```
<!-- Themes -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="style.css" id="theme1_css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="themes/dark.css" id="theme2_css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="themes/teal.css" id="theme3_css">
```

Comment: Save on HTTP requests and use a master class name in `<html>`. Change themes CSS to in such way they become `.dark body { /* props */ }`, `.teal body { /* props */ }`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page

Comment: Or see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735247/changing-the-href-of-a-link-tag-using-javascript and instead of elements by tag name, you can give the link an id and just target that to change it's href

Comment: it's not working out with onchange event @Stuart

Comment: The problem is, I'm using bootstrap too. so if i replace all link tags with new css tag then all link include the bootstrap will removed too. I don't want that way

Comment: How to do that with onchange event on select tag html? @Pete

Comment: `var link = document.getElementById('link-id');` // give the link tag and id
   `link.href = 'themes/' + x.value + '.css';`  // the value of the option should be the stylesheet name - eg dark or teal

Comment: Thanks @Pete you're my savior!

Answer (score 0):

So I edit the js script into this:

```
// Changing Themes
function changeBg(x){
    var link = document.getElementById('theme1_css');
    link.href = 'themes/' + x.value + '.css';
}
```

credit: thanks to @Pete

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that you can use the `disabled` property to set/unset themes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dark.css" data-theme="dark">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="light.css" data-theme="light">
```

And:

```
function setTheme(theme) {
    var styles = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]');
    styles.forEach(function(style) {
        var styleTheme = style.getAttribute('data-theme');
        style.disabled = styleTheme && styleTheme !== theme;
    });
}
```

Now set theme with something like:

```
setTheme('light');
```